# Reference to a entry in bibliography without generating it

Tags: bibtex, ref

In review articles it often happens that a figure is taken from another document which is mentioned in the `\caption` by a `\cite` macro. If such a caption  preceeds the first occurence of the corresponding `\cite` in the text, the number is increased when the caption is processed by TeX. Since the reader does not read the caption first, but will proceed with the main text until the next paragraph or headline, the numbering in the text has a gap.

Thus, I would like to reference an entry in the bibliography without creating it. a simple `\ref` does not work. Any ideas?

*Update*: The following exmaple produces the desired numbering in the text, but no citation in the caption. As soon as I use the comment version in the `\caption`, the numbering is not as I want it. (Don'T forget to re-run bibtex while testing).

```
\begin{filecontents}{./mybib.bib}
@misc{foo,
  author={Foo},
  title={Foo},
}
@misc{bar,
  author={Bar},
  title={Bar},
}
@misc{baz,
  author={Baz},
  title={Baz},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Taken from Foo\ref{foo}}
  %  \caption{Taken from Foo\cite{foo}}
  \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

Bar\cite{bar} and baz\cite{baz} have done some fascinating research,
which is best summarized as shown in Figure~\ref{fig:foo} (originally 
by Foo\cite{foo}).

\bibliography{./mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have updated the example to make it more clear what I want to achieve. (Remember to re-run bibtex). The numbering of the citations in the text is now as I want, but as soon as I use the `\cite` in the `\caption`, it changes. (Again, re-run bibtex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution that works with `natbib` when loaded with the `super` option; another one that works with standard LaTeX, as well as with `natbib` and the `numbers` option, is at the bottom.

```
\begin{filecontents}{./mybib.bib}
@misc{foo,
  author={Foo author},
  title={Foo title},
}
@misc{bar,
  author={Bar},
  title={Bar},
}
@misc{baz,
  author={Baz},
  title={Baz},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

% we patch the \bibcite macro to store the number of the
% citation     
\usepackage{xpatch,xstring,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\bibcite}{%
    \StrLeft{#2}{1}[\knall]%
    \StrRemoveBraces{\knall}[\peng]
    \global\csedef{defcite@#1}{\peng}
}{}{}

% the \deferredcite macro calls up the number stored above, if available;
% it does not itself cause a citation to be created. 
\newcommand{\deferredcite}[1]{%
\ifcsdef{defcite@#1}{\textsuperscript{\csuse{defcite@#1}}}{?}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Taken from Foo\deferredcite{foo}}
  \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

Bar\cite{bar} and baz\cite{baz} have done some fascinating research,
which is best summarized as shown in Figure~\ref{fig:foo} (originally 
by Foo\cite{foo}).

\bibliography{./mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here a solution for standard LaTeX without `natbib`. Output is identical, except that in-text citations are in brackets rather than as superscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} % to sort in order of appearance

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\oldbibcite\bibcite
\renewcommand{\bibcite}[2]{%
    \oldbibcite{#1}{#2}%
    \global\csedef{defcite@#1}{#2}}

\newcommand{\deferredcite}[1]{~[\ifcsdef{defcite@#1}{\csuse{defcite@#1}}{?}]}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption[Taken from Foo]{Taken from Foo\deferredcite{foo}}
  \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

Bar~\cite{bar} and baz~\cite{baz} have done some fascinating research,
which is best summarized as shown in Figure~\ref{fig:foo} (originally 
by Foo~\cite{foo}).

\bibliography{./mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've upvoted your answer. You may want to clarify, though, that the first solution expects `natbib` to be loaded with the option `super`. The second solution appears to work just fine with `natbib` if the package is loaded with the option `numbers`.

Comment: I have accepted your answer since it works for the example I've provided. However, the example was slightly oversimplified. If you change the author of the `foo` bibentry to `author={Foo, F and Bar, B and Baz, B}` it will no longer work since `\StrRemoveBraces` fails.

Comment: @PatrickHappel - I just tried it, and it works for me. In the aux file, I see `\bibcite{foo}{{3}{}{{Foo et~al.}}{{Foo, Bar, and Baz}}}`. From this line, `\StrLeft` should extract `{3}`, and the `\StrRemoveBraces` should strip the braces from this part only. Can you post the corresponding line from your aux file?

Comment: @MichaelPalmer: It depends on the bibliographystyle. Im my case, `et al.` is surrounded by `\emph`, which makes `\StrRemoveBraces` fail.

Comment: @PatrickHappel - I just don't see how that works. Can you update your question so as to show the non-working example?